# map a servlet in runtime

Tags: servlets

I need to map a servlet in **runtime**. Is there anyway of doing it? I saw a method called `addServlet` in `servletContext` Interface. But I couldn't find a way to access it.

Comment: Have a look at (MVC) front controller pattern. This way you can just end up with a single servlet. There are frameworks for this (JSF, Struts, SpringMVC, Wicket, Stripes, Play, etc). In depth explanation of the working can be found here: [design patterns web based applications](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3541077/design-patterns-web-based-applications/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can dynamically add servlets at runtime in Servlet 3.0. As you found, you do need access to the `ServletContext` in order to do this. The `ServletContext` is available from most web components, such as servlets or listeners. I'm not sure your use case for doing this, but here are a couple examples where you may access the ServletContext in order to add web components at runtime -

```
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {

    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        config.getServletContext().addServlet(...);
    }

    . . .
}

public class MyListener implements ServletContextListener {

    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce) {
        sce.getServletContext().addServlet(...);
    }

    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce) {}

}
```

Comment: thanks, this is what i was looking for. is there any method of doing it without `servlet 3.0`?

Comment: There is no equivalent prior to Servlet 3.0.

It's possible that there _may_ be some container-proprietary approaches, however. IIRC, Jetty may have allowed dynamic servlet registration before Servlet 3.0.

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to do this would be to use a filter, and then based on the request URL, load the servlet and call directly into it, as opposed to using the `chain.doFilter(req, resp);`  If you have an authentication filter; make sure to add this new filter lower on the web.xml so you don't accidentally forget to authenticate!

There is a library which could help you with this here: http://code.google.com/p/urlrewritefilter/

This filter works basically as I have described.

To be honest though; I think you should re-assess why you're doing this in the first place.  You likely don't need to do this and if you think about it you can probably find a way around whatever problem you're having using the good 'ole static servlet-mappings in your web.xml.  That decision is yours to make though.