# what is the simplest way to create a reverse proxy in tomcat?

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, proxy

I need a reverse proxy, which I will be able to configure the url mapping in runtime (in code) inside of my application that will be running in Tomcat 8.

Answer (score 0):

You might find this project useful - https://github.com/mitre/HTTP-Proxy-Servlet - it worked very well for me.

Comment: Tried it. How do I configure a dynamic URL mapping in runtime?

Comment: Since Tomcat 8 supports Servlet Spec 3.1 you should be able to use the method described here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7540792/map-a-servlet-in-runtime